# using the api trying to fill form value by pdf form field name

Tags: docusignapi

I am new to the docusign api and trying to wrap my head around the correct display form values in a PDF.

What I am trying to do, is display a PDF with a bunch of fields populated on the fly.

I am using the api call

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/${accountId}/envelopes
```

my payload looks like

```
    const payloadONE = {
    emailSubject : 'Please sign this document',
    documents : [{
        documentBase64: pdfBase64,
        name: 'Lorem Ipsum',
        fileExtension: 'pdf',
        documentId: '1'
    }
    ],
    recipients:{
        'signers':[
            {
            email: signerEmail,
            name: signerName,
            recipientId: '1',
            routingOrder: '1',
            clientUserId: 1000,
            tabs: {
                'signHereTabs': [
                    {
                        'documentId': '1', 'pageNumber': '1',
                        'recipientId': '1', 'tabLabel': 'SignHereTab',
                        'xPosition': '195', 'yPosition': '147'
                    }
                    ],
                textTabs : [
                    {
                        documentId: '1', anchorString: 'Phone',
                        pageNumber: '1', recipientId: '1', value: 'this is a test', anchorYOffset: 8
                    },
                    {
                        documentId: '1', anchorString: 'Fax',
                        pageNumber: '1', recipientId: '1', value: '2565551212', anchorYOffset: 8
                    },
                    {
                        documentId: '1', anchorString: 'Merchant\'s DBA',
                        pageNumber: '1', recipientId: '1', value: 'My DBA', anchorYOffset: 8
                    }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
status : 'sent'
}
```

Is this the correct process to populate form fields?

They will all be readonly. We just need signatures on a populated PDF..

My biggest issue currently is tabLabels kind of works (but the PDF i have to use has duplicate labels, but not duplicate form fieldnames). I can not no see how to populate the form field names. For example fax is in the header and a form field

I may be completely off base on my process and would love to know the correct way to accomplish this .

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I think what your issue is that you are using anchor tags but that duplicates the tags for you because the same text string shows in multiple places in the document?
You can try to resolve this by being a bit more specific about the anchor string or by placing the tag in a different way (x/y coordinates for example).